# RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for a custom model

Tags: pytorch

I'm trying to load the state_dict of my model to run an inference test.

This is the code to the model:

```
class AudioClassifier (nn.Module):
# ----------------------------
# Build the model architecture
# ----------------------------
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    conv_layers = []

    # First Convolution Block with Relu and Batch Norm. Use Kaiming Initialization
    self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(2, 8, kernel_size=(5, 5), stride=(2, 2), padding=(2, 2))
    self.relu1 = nn.ReLU()
    self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(8)
    init.kaiming_normal_(self.conv1.weight, a=0.1)
    self.conv1.bias.data.zero_()
    conv_layers += [self.conv1, self.relu1, self.bn1]

    # Second Convolution Block
    self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(8, 16, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1))
    self.relu2 = nn.ReLU()
    self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(16)
    init.kaiming_normal_(self.conv2.weight, a=0.1)
    self.conv2.bias.data.zero_()
    conv_layers += [self.conv2, self.relu2, self.bn2]

    # Third Convolution Block
    self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(16, 32, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1))
    self.relu3 = nn.ReLU()
    self.bn3 = nn.BatchNorm2d(32)
    init.kaiming_normal_(self.conv3.weight, a=0.1)
    self.conv3.bias.data.zero_()
    conv_layers += [self.conv3, self.relu3, self.bn3]

    # Fourth Convolution Block
    self.conv4 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1))
    self.relu4 = nn.ReLU()
    self.bn4 = nn.BatchNorm2d(64)
    init.kaiming_normal_(self.conv4.weight, a=0.1)
    self.conv4.bias.data.zero_()
    conv_layers += [self.conv4, self.relu4, self.bn4]

    # Fifth Convolution Block
    self.conv5 = nn.Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1))
    self.relu5 = nn.ReLU()
    self.bn5 = nn.BatchNorm2d(128)
    init.kaiming_normal_(self.conv5.weight, a=0.1)
    self.conv5.bias.data.zero_()
    conv_layers += [self.conv5, self.relu5, self.bn5]
    
    # Linear Classifier
    self.ap = nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d(output_size=1)
    self.lin = nn.Linear(in_features=128, out_features=10)

    # Wrap the Convolutional Blocks
    self.conv = nn.Sequential(*conv_layers)
     
# ----------------------------
# Forward pass computations
# ----------------------------
def forward(self, x):
    # Run the convolutional blocks
    x = self.conv(x)

    # Adaptive pool and flatten for input to linear layer
    x = self.ap(x)
    x = x.view(x.shape[0], -1)

    # Linear layer
    x = self.lin(x)

    # Final output
    return x
```

Then I ran a training session and save the model as such:

```
for fold, (train_idx,val_idx) in enumerate(splits.split(np.arange(len(dataset)))):

    print('Fold {}'.format(fold + 1))

    train_sampler = SubsetRandomSampler(train_idx)
    test_sampler = SubsetRandomSampler(val_idx)
    train_loader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batch_size, sampler=train_sampler)
    test_loader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batch_size, sampler=test_sampler)
    
    model = AudioClassifier()
    model.to(device)
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)

    history = {'train_loss': [], 'test_loss': [],'train_acc':[],'test_acc':[]}

    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        train_loss, train_correct=train_epoch(model,device,train_loader,criterion,optimizer)
        test_loss, test_correct=valid_epoch(model,device,test_loader,criterion)

        train_loss = train_loss / len(train_loader.sampler)
        train_acc = train_correct / len(train_loader.sampler) * 100
        test_loss = test_loss / len(test_loader.sampler)
        test_acc = test_correct / len(test_loader.sampler) * 100

        print("Epoch:{}/{} AVG Training Loss:{:.3f} | AVG Test Loss:{:.3f} | AVG Training Acc {:.2f} % | AVG Test Acc {:.2f} %".format(epoch + 1,
                                                                                                             num_epochs,
                                                                                                             train_loss,
                                                                                                             test_loss,
                                                                                                             train_acc,
                                                                                                             test_acc))
        history['train_loss'].append(train_loss)
        history['test_loss'].append(test_loss)
        history['train_acc'].append(train_acc)
        history['test_acc'].append(test_acc)
    foldperf['fold{}'.format(fold+1)] = history 

torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'model_v1.pth')
```

I used this code as usual to load it:

```
model = AudioClassifier()
model.load_state_dict(torch.load('model_v1.pth'))
model.eval()
```

Usually it would work without issue, however now I got this error instead:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[18], line 80
     77         return x
     79 model = AudioClassifier()
---> 80 model.load_state_dict(torch.load('model_v1.pth'))
     81 model.eval()

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py:2041, in Module.load_state_dict(self, state_dict, strict)
   2036         error_msgs.insert(
   2037             0, 'Missing key(s) in state_dict: {}. '.format(
   2038                 ', '.join('"{}"'.format(k) for k in missing_keys)))
   2040 if len(error_msgs) > 0:
-> 2041     raise RuntimeError('Error(s) in loading state_dict for {}:\n\t{}'.format(
   2042                        self.__class__.__name__, "\n\t".join(error_msgs)))
   2043 return _IncompatibleKeys(missing_keys, unexpected_keys)

RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for AudioClassifier:
    Missing key(s) in state_dict: "conv5.weight", "conv5.bias", "bn5.weight", "bn5.bias", "bn5.running_mean", "bn5.running_var", "conv.12.weight", "conv.12.bias", "conv.14.weight", "conv.14.bias", "conv.14.running_mean", "conv.14.running_var". 
    size mismatch for lin.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([10, 64]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([10, 128]).
```

I trained and saved the model a while ago. I downloaded the .pth file and saved it in my computer for future use and when I want to open it again it did not work.

What might be the issue here? Thanks.

Comment: Please give code of your model and how you save it.

Comment: added as per requested.